# Pair of straight lines as a conic section

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

Can someone tell me how is pair of straight lines a conic section. I know the equation is of second degree and other mathematical facts prove that. But how to visualise it? How is a pair of straight lines formed when a plane intersects a cone?

Comment: Take the plane to contain the axis of the cone.

Comment: See Wikipedia's ["Degenerate conic" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_conic), which describes not only the *crossed lines* case (where the plane contains the cone's axis) but the *parallel lines* case (where the cone itself degenerates into a cylinder).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes an image is worth a thousand words:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take the cone $$
z^2 = x^2 + y^2
$$
Intersect it with the $y = 0$ plane to get
$$
z^2 = x^2 + 0^2 = x^2
$$
so that 
$$
z = \pm x
$$
That's a pair of lines in the $y=0$ plane.

If you think of $z$ as "up and down", then $z^2 = x^2 + y^2$ is a double cone, and looks like an egg-cup or hourglass. You slice this with a vertical plane like $y = 0$, and you get a pair of the generating lines for the double-cone.

Answer (score 0):

"If a cone is cut by a plane through the vertex, the section is a triangle." (Apollonius, *Conics, I, 3*). Ignore the base of the triangle, which is a straight line within the circular base of the cone, and you have the two intersecting straight lines on the conic surface.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of this as a degenerate hyperbola, e.g., $$y=\lim_{a\to0}\pm\sqrt{a+x^2}$$